# Username availability check using java and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to check username availability in mysql database using javascript function in jsp page upon clicking submit button here is the code:

```
    <button type="button" class="signUpbtn" id="btn1" onclick="return check();" />Sign Up</button>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" class="signInbtn" VALUE="Sign In" onClick="submitFunction(1)">
                </div>
            </div>
                <script> 
                    function check(){
                        <%
        String user = request.getParameter("userName");
        user = (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
        String sql = "select * from user where UserName = ?" ;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ps = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs == null){
            response.sendRedirect("ManagerSignUp.jsp");
        }
        else{
           %>
         alert("Please Choose another username!");
<%} %>
                               }
   </script>
```

MysqlConnection is a class for database connection stuff (i.e. not an error)

The problem is when I try to signup using a non-existing username it still gives the message that indicates duplicate username above.

another problem is rs.next() and rs.equal() and all these methods destroy my html form!!

Any Help?!!

Comment: You can't run Java code in a JavaScript tag. Why? The Java code will be executed while _rendering_ the page on the _server_ while the JavaScript code will be executed in the user's _browser_.

Comment: so what can I do different?

Comment: You'd need to do a request from your JavaScript code (e.g. an AJAX request) and handle it in Java on the server. There are lots of tutorials on the net on how to do that but you probably should start at the basics.

Comment: It is not a good practice to include java code in jsp. you could make a GET request that would be fired by javascript and let a servlet handles the request and do your database authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security issues aside (see comments), your `ResultSet rs` is most likely never null. Try `rs.next()`, which should return false if there was no data in the result.

Comment: I have a problem with rs.next() it ruins the html form and I can't find a solution for that or even a reason!

Comment: What happens exactly? Where do you run rs.next()?

Comment: in the condition : if(rs.next()) instead of ==null

Comment: Oh, try checking for false instead:  `if(rs.next() == false)` or `if(!rs.next())`  .

Answer (score 0):

not sure why `rs.next()` is not working for you but you can try using `rs.isBeforeFirst()` if the query worked then there will be a row generated and this will return true, else it will return false as there are no rows in rs